# Profiling GPU code for power draw and resource utilization

Tags: performance, profiling, opencl, gpu

I am trying to calculate the power consumption of different kernels of my OpenCL code for my [MJPEG decoder](https://superuser.com/questions/1280543/power-consumption-of-opencl-code-running-on-a-nvidia-gpu). I used the following command to calculate the power consumption and resource utilization of various kernels by using the following command (This is just an example):

`nvidia-smi -q -d POWER,UTILIZATION -i 0 -l -f out.log`

The power consumption of every kernel is more or less the same and "sebf" explained why that is the case in his comments.

[image]

The x-axis represents the number of instances at which the power was calculated and the y-axis represents the power consumption.As one can see, when all the functions are running on the GPU, the application runs for a longer time. However, the peak power consumption in ALL scenarios is more or less the same.

(In order to calculate the power consumption of a function on the GPU, I let the other functions run as C code while that specific function was run as an OpenCL kernel).

**After I also logged the utilization percentages, I noticed the percentages for each of the scenarios were different.** The average GPU utilization was about 44 % for upsampling, 22 % for iqzz, 8 % for color conversion, 15 % for IDCT and 29 % for running all functions on the GPU.

for example, the data for one instance of iqzz is as follows:

```
==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                           : Wed Jan  3 18:22:12 2018
Driver Version                      : 352.21

Attached GPUs                       : 2
GPU 0000:03:00.0
    Utilization
        Gpu                         : 22 %
        Memory                      : 0 %
        Encoder                     : 0 %
        Decoder                     : 0 %
    GPU Utilization Samples
        Duration                    : 16.47 sec
        Number of Samples           : 99
        Max                         : 22 %
        Min                         : 19 %
        Avg                         : 21 %
    Memory Utilization Samples
        Duration                    : 16.47 sec
        Number of Samples           : 99
        Max                         : 0 %
        Min                         : 0 %
        Avg                         : 0 %
    ENC Utilization Samples
        Duration                    : 16.47 sec
        Number of Samples           : 99
        Max                         : 0 %
        Min                         : 0 %
        Avg                         : 0 %
    DEC Utilization Samples
        Duration                    : 16.47 sec
        Number of Samples           : 99
        Max                         : 0 %
        Min                         : 0 %
        Avg                         : 0 %
    Power Readings
        Power Management            : Supported
        Power Draw                  : 52.60 W
        Power Limit                 : 225.00 W
        Default Power Limit         : 225.00 W
        Enforced Power Limit        : 225.00 W
        Min Power Limit             : 150.00 W
        Max Power Limit             : 225.00 W
    Power Samples
        Duration                    : 1.78 sec
        Number of Samples           : 119
        Max                         : 52.61 W
        Min                         : 52.41 W
        Avg                         : 52.51 W
```

An answer for [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1013001/relation-between-gpu-utilization-and-graphic-cards-power-consumption) question states that utilization percentage indicates the percentage of time the GPU is active.

***So, can we use the utilization percentages for calculating the power consumption of each scenario?*** For example, in the case of iqzz, can we do `0.22 * 52.6 W`(The other instances in the log file are similar to the one I have posted.) ?

Please let me know whether or not my approach towards calculating GPU power is correct?

My programming framework is OpenCL and my GPU is Tesla K20c.

**EDIT:**

I studied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040426/why-do-nvprof-and-nvidia-smi-report-different-results-on-power?rq=1) answer and [this](http://sedici.unlp.edu.ar/bitstream/handle/10915/63943/Documento_completo.pdf?sequence=1) paper and they both mention the use of NVML (Nvidia Management Library) for calculating the power consumption.

Comment: Removing `cuda` tag, adding `opencl` tag.  NVML has no direct connection to CUDA, and can be used with OpenCL.  NVML is not a **tool** it is a library.  Tools can be built on top of the NVML library, and one such tool built on top of NVML is `nvidia-smi` (which is also usable with OpenCL, and not restricted to CUDA).

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you for the information about NVML. Could I use the utilization percentages I got from `nvidia-smi` to determine the actual power consumption of my kernels?

Comment: I wouldn't multiply the power consumption measurements by the utilization percentage.  The `nvidia-smi` tool is taking sampled measurements in each case.  For the power consumption, imagine that there is a "real" power consumption curve, and `nvidia-smi` is telling you what the magnitude of that curve is at 119 sample points.  The magnitude varies but is between 52.41W and 52.61W.  That says to me, over the 1.78 second interval, sampled at 119 points, the power consumption was basically constant at 52.5W.  I wouldn't multiply that number by 0.22 if I were interested in that 1.78s interval.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Okay I understand your explanation. Why do I only see a negligible increase in power when I run all the kernels together on the GPU? One can see that it takes longer to run the kernels but what can I do to increase the power consumption of the GPU?

Comment: In order to really push the power consumption of a GPU up near its limit, you would usually need a fairly specific code - say a large matrix-matrix multiply.  If you're not doing something like that, it's possible that a lot of codes are just going to run at a fairly low power level.  Certainly, anything you can do to "parallelize the code more" may help drive up the power consumption.  But unless you really get into the sweet spot of that GPU, you may not see much difference.

Comment: @RobertCrovella How can I find the power consumed by the PCI-bus by using `nvidia-smi`?

Comment: I have no idea.  I'm not sure what you mean by "the power consumed by the PCI-bus" and I'm reasonably confident NVML doesn't give you any mechanism to inspect it.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I meant the energy that is consumed when transferring data to and from the device.